# WPF: gauge value converter

Tags: wpf, xaml

So i have simple `Gauge` class with static `int` property that implement `Propertychanged`:

```
TotalPacketsSent
```

This `property` is raising all the time and i want to wrote simple `converter` and send this `converter` this `property` `value` and return some value base on this `property`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
int val = (int)value;
    double percentage = ((double)MyClass.TotalPacketsSent / MyClass.TotalPacketsInList) * 100;
    return percentage;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Under `Window.Resources` i have this:

```
<Convertors:GaugeValueConverter x:Key="GaugeValueConverter"/>
```

And this is my `Gause`:

```
<Controllers:Gauge x:Name="gauge"
                   Value="{Binding Path=(my:MyClass.TotalPacketsSent), Converter={StaticResource GaugeValueConverter}}"
                   Minimum="0"
                   Maximum="100"/>
```

So my issue is that my `converter` not working at all, i mean that i cannot see that this even executed.
Any ideas why ?

Edit:

This `property` is changing all the time and i have `Label` i am using this way to show its value:

```
Content="{Binding Path=(my:MyClass.TotalPacketsSent)}"
```

And this works fine.

Comment: Does the converter even care about the value it receives? It looks like you're binding to a static property there, which I'm not sure would be working at all.

Comment: Yes, please see my edit inside Convert function

Comment: This property (TotalPacketsSent) is changing all the time, as i mention i have simple label that show this propert value in real time and this works fine

Comment: `MyClass.TotalPacketsSent` doesn't seem to make much sense in the converter. What is MyClass supposed to be here? A property of the converter class? Do you ever set it anywhere? What you actually need seems to be a MultiBinding to `MyClass.TotalPacketsSent` and `MyClass.TotalPacketsInList` with a multi-value converter.

Comment: It’s good that the static property is simple (does it even have a type or an implementation?) and that the Label is simple, but does the simple property raise a simple static property changed notification?

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the `value` argument as an `int` and then not using it.

I imagine what you're looking for is something like (deriving from `IMultiValueConverter` rather than `IValueConverter`):

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    double totalPacketsSent = (double)values[0];
    double totalPacketsInList = (double)values[1];

    // further validation for handling divide by zero, etc. may need to go here

    return totalPacketsSent / totalPacketsInList * 100
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
<Controllers:Gauge x:Name="gauge" Minimum="0" Maximum="100">
    <Controllers:Gauge.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GaugeValueConverter}">
            <Binding Path="(my:MyClass.TotalPacketsSent)" />
            <Binding Path="(my:MyClass.TotalPacketsInList)" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Controllers:Gauge.Value>
</Controllers:Gauge>
```